# sorting in datagrid lost on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

```
//Sort User Table
private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
{
    DataTable dataTable = BindGridView(Session["useremail"].ToString()).Tables[0];
    if (dataTable != null)
    {
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        dataView.Sort = sortExpression + direction;

        UserTable.DataSource = dataView;
        UserTable.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
    if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
        SortGridView(sortExpression, " ASC");
    }

    else
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
        SortGridView(sortExpression, " DESC");
    }
}

public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
        return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
    }
    set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; }
}
```

When I Edit a user and update the edit or do some search, and clear the search the page loads and the sort is lost,

```
private DataSet BindGridView(string email)
    {
        .......
    }

 protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      .....
       BindGridView(Session["useremail"].ToString());
    }
```

everytime the page loads or some postback is done the sort is lost how to retain the sort.

Page load

```
 if (PermissionList.Any(item => item.Equals("Edit user")))        
     {            
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindGridView(Session["useremail"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Whats in your Page_Load?

Comment: This is basically the same question you have asked previously. Anywhere you Bind() the data you must also sort it prior to the binding so the Data is sorted when bound to the control.

Comment: Was going to post an answer, but Lloyd be me.  His comment is the correct answer.

Comment: hi Lloyd,How can I do that. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you perform a new sort on your gridview, store the sort expression in a hidden label, or field, and anytime you re-load/bind your gridview, use your saved sort expression to re-sort the table.

.aspx

```
<asp:Label id="lblHidSortExp" runat="server" visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sortExpression = lblHidSortExp.Text;
    if(sortExpression == e.SortExpression)
        sortExpression += " DESC";
    else
        sortExpression == e.SortExpression;

   //not sure if this is exactly how you get your datatable, but you get the idea
   DataView myView = new DataView(BindGridView(Session["useremail"].ToString()).Tables[0]);
   myView.Sort = sortExpression;
   marksGridView.DataSource = myView;
   marksGridView.DataBind();

   //save sort state
   lblHidSortExp.Text = sortExpression;
}
```

So say in your update function, use your saved sort exp

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  .....//do update in db
   //reload your table in dataview
   DataView myView = new DataView(/*load table*/);
   //do sort
   myView.Sort = lblHidSortExp.Text;
   //bind gridview
   marksGridView.DataSource = myView;
   marksGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: How can I store the sort expression in a hidden label, any code will help. thanks

Comment: @Mark updated my answer. Meant for guidance, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the way I aproached this was to save the sort values in the session, then just reset them in Page_load after they are lost.

Comment: You don't need to use Session memory for this

Comment: @Shredder I will look into doing it the way you suggested here myself with hidden fields. Thanks